# rust tokio trait bounds were not satisfied on forward method

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I upgraded `wrap` and `tokio` in my rust project and after the upgrade, the forward method got an error. I searched through the documentation but there was no forward method in the new version of tokio framework.

### Error

```
error[E0599]: the method `forward` exists for struct `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied


tokio::task::spawn(client_rcv.forward(client_ws_sender).map(|result| {
                                      ^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
40 | pub struct UnboundedReceiver<T> {
   | -------------------------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `_: warp::Stream`
   | doesn't satisfy `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: StreamExt`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: warp::Stream`
           which is required by `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: StreamExt`
           `&tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: warp::Stream`
           which is required by `&tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: StreamExt`
           `&mut tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: warp::Stream`
           which is required by `&mut tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: StreamExt`
```

#### Code:

```rust
let (client_ws_sender, mut client_ws_rcv) = ws.split();
let (client_sender, client_rcv) = mpsc::unbounded_channel();

tokio::task::spawn(client_rcv.forward(client_ws_sender).map(|result| {
    if let Err(e) = result {
        eprintln!("error sending websocket msg: {}", e);
    }
}));
```

#### Cargo Dependecies:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1.6.0", features = ["full"] }
warp = "0.3.1"
serde = {version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
futures = { version = "0.3", default-features = false }
uuid = { version = "0.8.2", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most telling lines of that error message are the following:

```
   | doesn't satisfy `_: warp::Stream`
   | doesn't satisfy `tokio::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<_>: StreamExt`
```

The [`forward`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.forward) method is defined in the [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) trait; due to [a blanket implementation](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#impl-StreamExt), anything that implements [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) also implements `StreamExt`.  However, as of Tokio v1.6.0, [`UnboundedReceiver`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.UnboundedReceiver.html) no longer implements `Stream`.  The documentation instead states:

> This receiver can be turned into a `Stream` using [`UnboundedReceiverStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-stream/0.1/tokio_stream/wrappers/struct.UnboundedReceiverStream.html).

Hence:

```rust
let (client_ws_sender, mut client_ws_rcv) = ws.split();
let (client_sender, client_rcv) = mpsc::unbounded_channel();
let client_rcv = UnboundedReceiverStream::new(client_rcv);  // <-- this

tokio::task::spawn(client_rcv.forward(client_ws_sender).map(|result| {
    if let Err(e) = result {
        eprintln!("error sending websocket msg: {}", e);
    }
}));
```